# Reuse a component in other ones in React(AntDesign)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm new to react so apologies for the basic question.
I have a header component as below which I want to use in my other components

```
const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;


const NavHeader = (Components: any) => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout className="site-layout">
        <Header className="site-layout-background" style={{padding: 0,}}/>
        <Content>
            Content of the page
        </Content>
        <Footer>
          My Footer
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default NavHeader;

How can I reuse this code considering my pages should be placed inside the `<Content></Content>` part of the header?
```

Comment: are you wanting to reuse the NavHeader component or the other components?

Comment: @ColinHale I want to use the header inside my other components

Comment: You want to use Header or NavHeader? either way just export The Header or NavHeader then import that in the component you want to use

Comment: @ColinHale The section inside this header is where the rest of the content goes. So I cant just call it somewhere else

I want to use another component in it like as props

<Content>
  <AnotherComponent />
</Content>

Comment: When you say this header, Are you referring to the NavHeader Component or the Header component? You have two header components in there. I don't know which one you want to reuse

Comment: NavHeader

The main one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to pass a prop to the NavHeader component as a React.ReactElement, then you can display that in the content area. Here is a quick codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-component-as-prop-9s070b?file=/src/NavHeader.tsx:28-226

```
interface Props {
content:React.ReactElement;
}

const NavHeader: React.FC:<Props> = ({content}) => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout className="site-layout">
        <Header className="site-layout-background" style={{padding: 0,}}/>
        <Content>
            {content}
        </Content>
        <Footer>
          My Footer
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default NavHeader;
```

Then to use the component:

```
<NavHeader content={<h1>Custom Component</h1>} />
```